# ValueError: shapes (19,11) and (5,1) not aligned: 11 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook

How to fix the error, is it to make the ones matrix a single column?
This is mutiple linear regression.
Is this the right way to gradient descent/error in for mutiple linear regression?
to do it for each x or as a whole?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

import os
path = os.getcwd() + '\farmExpense.txt'

x1=[]
x2=[]
x3=[]
x4=[]
y=[]
file = open("farmExpense.txt","r")
while True:
line = file.readline()
if not line:
    break
else:
    values = line.split(",")
    x1.append(float(values[0]))
    x2.append(float(values[1]))
    x3.append(float(values[2]))
    x4.append(float(values[3]))
    y.append(float(values[4].rstrip("\n")))
file.close()

x1 = np.matrix(x1).T
x2 = np.matrix(x2).T
x3 = np.matrix(x3).T
x4 = np.matrix(x4).T
y = np.matrix(y).T

x = np.hstack((x1,x2,x3,x4))
x = np.matrix(x)
print(x)

lm.fit(x,y)
theta0 = lm.intercept_[0]
theta1 = lm.coef_[0][0]
theta2 = lm.coef_[0][1]
theta3 = lm.coef_[0][2]
theta4 = lm.coef_[0][3]
print("The equation that best models our data is:")
print("y=",theta0,"+",theta1,"*X1 +",theta2,"*X2 +",theta3,"*X3 +",theta4, "*X4")

#Initial Guess for Weights in hypothesis function
theta0 = 1
theta1 = 0.5
theta2 = 0.2
theta3 = 0.3
theta4 = 0.6

#learning rate 
alpha = 0.011

#convergence so we know when to stop (0.1 -> converage after 1 decimal spot, 0.01 converage after 2 decimal spots)
conv = 0.001

m = len(x)
print(len(x))

x1 = np.matrix(x1).T
x2 = np.matrix(x2).T
x3 = np.matrix(x3).T
x4 = np.matrix(x4).T
y = np.matrix(y).T

theta =  np.array([[1],[0.5],[0.2],[0.3],[0.6]])
print(theta)

ones = np.ones((m,1))
print(ones)

x = np.hstack((ones,x))

previousCost = 0
numSteps = 0
while True:

    #Counts how many times the gradient descent takes to reach the minimum cost
    numSteps = numSteps + 1

    #create the hypothesis matrix
    #Its the dot product betwween the x matrix and the Theta matrix
    hypothesis = x.dot(theta) 

    #create the error matrix
    #Its the hypothesis matrix subtracted by the y matrix
    error = (hypothesis-y)

    #Calculate the sum of the errors squared
    #Its the dot product between the transpose of the error matrix and the non transposed error matrix
    totalError = error.T.dot(error)

    #Calculate the cost
    #Its 1/(2m) multiplied by the total error
    cost = (1/(2*m)*totalError)

    #Checking if the cost has converged to less than the conversion parameter
    if abs(previousCost - cost) <= conv:
        break
    else:
        #Calculate new alpha error for theta0
        #Its the dot product of the transposed error matrix with the first column of the x matrix x[:,0]
        alphaError0 =  error.T.dot(x[:, 0])
    
        #Calculate new alpha error for theta1
        #Its the dot product of the transposed error matrix with the second column of the x matrix x[:,1]        
        alphaError1 =  error.T.dot(x[:, 1])
    
        #Calculate the new theta0 value
        #Its the theta0 value - alpha/m multiplied by alphaError0
        theta0 = (theta0-alpha/m*alphaError0)
    
        #Calculate the new theta1 value
        #Its the theta1 value - alpha/m multiplied by alphaError1
        theta1 = (theta1-alpha/m*alphaError1)

        #Put the new theta values into the theta matrix
        theta = np.matrix([[theta0[0,0]],[theta1[0,0]]])
    
        #reset the previous cost for next comparison
        previousCost = cost
```

Comment: Full error message please

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to make the matrix a single column.

What is happening is you have one variable that is shape (19, 11) and another variable that is (5, 1).

When taking a dot product so basically when you multiply the two variables together by using `*` or `.dot`, in order for it to work the last index of the first variable and the first index of the second variable must be the same so `.dot` with shapes: (19, 11) and (11, 1) will work or (19, 5) and (5 1) will work but once those middle dimensions don't match you have a problem.

You haven't specified where the error is, but I would run checks on the shapes of variables where you use .dot or *.

Comment: Now, I got any new error:    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9908/4272238332.py in <module>
     23 
     24     #Checking if the cost has converged to less than the conversion parameter
---> 25     if abs(previousCost - cost) <= conv:
     26         break
     27     else:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I am not clear as to what lines this is happening in. Can you please tell me that. Thanks.